# How to know if IAM user is used in any aws services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses, amazon-cloudfront

I am using below services of aws and for that their are IAM users exists and now i want to delete all IAM users and want to create new users and want to apply that users to the services.

And i want to replace old users from services and want to add new created users to the services. So how i achieve this?

**Services**:

1) s3
2) ses
3) cloudfront
4) lambda (for forwarding ses emails)

And i have one more question, If we copy the old users permission to the new one. So will it impact any service?

> Basically, I want to remove old users and create new users with same old users policies.

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

First Question:
Simple answer on how to go about doing this is as below:

```
1. Replace on one account at a time.
2. You check the existing user accounts' Permissions and Groups tabs in IAM
3. Make note of all access, groups and roles the old accounts have assigned
4. Create the new user accounts with same permissions
5. Test the access works same with new accounts as it was working with old accounts
```

Second Question: If we copy the old users permission to the new one. So will it impact any service?

Answer: 
You should not have major impact if the users are console users only. But if there are users that have programmatic access, then you might have be extra careful. These accounts could be used by developers or services on AWS or elsewhere. You might have to go through the IAM user in detail to see if any of these users have their purpose and places of use documented. So, is they are service accounts or used to carry out automated actions, then you must thoroughly test that account's usage and then delete the old account.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But your answer is not clear to me, As i haven't created the previous user by my own and i don't have knowledge about IAM.

Comment: So can you please answer in little bit more detail?

Comment: [AWS Doco](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_create-admin-group.html)

This is a good starting point to creating a user account and a group.

[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmE3p2zPaTU)

This video is also a good reference, but she has already created some policies, so your screens will look different. Like I asked in the first question, try to follow that approach...